# Ping a url when IOS application crashes?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, exception

I want to ping a url on my website whenever my IOS application crashes.  Where is the best place to put an exception catcher that can quickly ping an external url and then rethrow the exception to the OS?

Answer (score 7):

We're using [CrashKit](https://github.com/kaler/CrashKit) on one of our iPad apps to collect the crash log at the moment of a crash and send it to our server for analysis. Of course you could instead ping a URL or do whatever you want to add in the signal/exception handling routine.

The library is very easy to integrate, I suggest you have a look at it.

Comment: What it does sounds really dangerous. EXC_BAD_ACCESS, for instance could mean the entire runtime is hosed.  I don't see how you can reliably expect to do anything let alone send an email in such circumstances.

Comment: It's worked fine for us so far though, hundreds of crash logs collected that way.

Comment: Fine in your situation, but I'm not sure how happy I would be as a customer to have code like that in an application I bought.  It sounds like a security hole just waiting to happen.

Answer (score 4):

Check out http://chaosinmotion.com/blog/?p=423